# What does the Swift 2 method signature for application:openURL:options: look like?

Tags: ios, swift, url-scheme, openurl

I'm working on the Swift version of an app that handles custom URL schemes.

The method you need to implement changed in iOS 9.

The Objective-C version of the method works fine in an Objective-C app:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<NSString *,
                     id> *)options
{
  //my code here
}
```

However, in my Swift app, the equivalent function:

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
  openURL: NSURL,
  options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool
{
  //My code here
}
```

Is never called when I run the app on an iOS 9 device. When I invoke my custom URL scheme in Safari, I get prompted 'Open in "appname"?', and when I tap open, it brings my app back to the foreground, but the above method does not get called.

There must be some subtle mismatch in my method signature, but I can't see it. What am I doing wrong? I've tried various variations, none of which work.

Comment: is your custom URL scheme has http or https protocol?

Comment: From Apple Developer : This method is not called if your implementations return false from both the application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions: and application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: methods. Maybe you missed this ? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html?hl=ar#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:openURL:options:

Comment: @ZellB, thanks for the suggestion but that's not it. My `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is returning true

Comment: @bat, I am implementing a custom URL PROTOCOL, e.g. `myurl://parameters`. It's not using the HTTP or HTTPS protocols, but my own custom protocol.

Comment: @DuncanC let Xcode autocomplete, looks like it is wrong to me. The correct would be  `func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {`

Comment: Autocomplete isn't working for some reason, and pasting your function definition in doesn't work either, nor does copying the function definition from the header of the UIApplicationDelegate protocol. Very strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem appears to have been a red herring caused by a corrupted project. I created a new project file and copied the same code in and in the new project, `application:openURL:options:` is called correctly.

This is a very strange problem. If I delete "AppDelegate.swift" in the malfunctioning project and replace it with an AppDelegate.m/AppDelegate.h, then the `application:openURL:options:` is called correctly in the Objective-C version.

My suspicion is that there is an intermittent bug in Xcode that causes some projects to fail to cal your app delegate's `application:openURL:options:` when the app delegate in Swift.

If you are having the same problem you may want to create a new project, set up your info.plist, and copy over the `application:openURL:options:` method to see if the new project calls your method.

Answer (score 0):

Function signature (iOS9) is:

```
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool
```

And if you want to test it working, just copy this into your app delegate:

```
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool 
{
        print("Scheme: \(url.scheme)")
        print("Host: \(url.host)")
        print("Path: \(url.path)")
        print("Query String: \(url.query)")

        // DEBUG: get all key-value pairs in options also
        for (key, value) in options {
            print("Key: \(key), Value: \(value)")
        }
        return true
}
```

Also remember to add the "scheme" (app name) to your info.plist file. Call from Safari on the phone like this

> scheme://host/path?query